# POST HTML form results to api and get response in flask

Tags: python, html, json, api, flask

I am relatively very new to `Flask` and web app development in general.
So, I have built a basic login page, and I have a web `API` with ldap authentication to authenticate users in my organization.
I am trying to send the login form results to the web `API` url, it accepts 2 parameters: username and password.

This is my login.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css">
&#123;% block body %&#125;

<form action="/login2" method="POST">
<div class="login">
<div class="login-screen">
<div class="app-title">
<h1>Login</h1>
</div>
<div class="login-form">
<div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" name="username">
<label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label></div>
<div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" name="password">
<label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label></div>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
&#123;% endblock %&#125;
```

And this is the relevant `Flask` code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    
    return render_template('login.html')
    
@app.route('/login2', methods=['POST'])
def logger():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = "my url to authenticate"
        response = requests.post(url, json={"username": "myusername","password": "mypassword"}, verify=False)
        data = request.get_json()
        print(data)
        return "Done"
```

Right now, I was just trying to test the `API` by sending my valid credentials to the`API`, but it always returns None instead of the actual result which it should have returned.

The problem isn't with the `API`, because it works on terminal with `CURL`.

Ideally I would like to send the login details to the `API`.

Then:

- if the `API` response code is `200`, the authentication is successful
- if the `API` response code is `401`, the authentication should fail, and I can add a message for that and redirect them back

Please help
UPDATE:
So, this is my login.html now. I am trying to send the form data with JS now from login.html. But, I am still not sure how I can get the response back, and also this code is giving no output in console, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" type="text/css">
&#123;% block body %&#125;

<body>
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
<div class="login">
<div class="login-screen">
<div class="app-title">
<h1>Login</h1>
</div>
<div class="login-form">
<div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" name="username">
<label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label></div>
<div class="control-group">
                <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" name="password">
<label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label></div>
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<script>
    const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault;
        
        const formData = new FormData(this);
        url = "url to authenticate"
        response = requests.post(url, json={"username": "myusername","password": "mypassword"}, verify=False)
        data = request.get_json()
        console.log(data)
        flash(data)
    });


</script>

</body>

&#123;% endblock %&#125;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your second update. In the first version of your code:

```py
response = requests.post(url, json={"username": "myusername","password": "mypassword"}, verify=False)
data = request.get_json()
print(data)
```

In these lines, you send a request to your auth API with a Python library called `requests`, it returns the response to the `response` variable. Note the `response` variable contains the info returned by your auth API (you call call `json()` method on it to obtain the JSON body). However, then you call `get_json()` on Flask's `request` object with `request.get_json()` instead of call `response.json()`. That's why you always got `None`.

Hence, you should use the code below:

```py
response = requests.post(url, json={"username": "myusername","password": "mypassword"}, verify=False)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Can you also help me with how I can use the actual form data instead of passing my variables to test it?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much again!